# node.js process.env not working in command line

Tags: node.js, command-line, environment

I'm taking an online course on writing block-chain from scratch.
The course utilizes javascript and node.js.
I am very new to these technologies but followed the course so far to the T.
i'm pasting the relevant code - the app file (index):

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Blockchain = require('../blockchain');
const P2pServer = require('./p2p-server');

const HTTP_PORT = process.env.HTTP_PORT || 3001;

const app = express();
const bc = new Blockchain();
const p2pServer = new P2pServer(bc);

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/blocks', (req, res) => {
    res.json(bc.chain);
});

app.post('/mine', (req, res) => {
    const block = bc.addBlock(req.body.data);
    console.log(`New blovk added: ${block.toString()}`);

    res.redirect('/blocks');
});

app.listen(HTTP_PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${HTTP_PORT}`));
p2pServer.listen();
```

and the code from p2p-server.js:

```
const Websocket = require('ws');

const P2P_PORT = process.env.P2P_PORT || 5001;
const peers = process.env.PEERS ? process.env.PEERS.split(',') : [];
//HTTP_PORT=3002 P2P_PORT=5003 PEERS=ws://localhost:5001 npm run dev

class P2pServer {
    constructor(blockchain) {
        this.blockchain = blockchain;
        this.sockets = [];
    }

    listen() {
        const server = new Websocket.Server({ port: P2P_PORT });
        server.on('connection', socket =>this.connectSocket(socket));

        this.connectToPeers();

        console.log(`listening to peer-to-peer connections on: ${P2P_PORT}`);
    }

    connectToPeers() {
        peers.forEach(peer => {
            const socket = new Websocket(peer);

            socket.on('open', () => this.connectSocket(socket));
        });
    }

    connectSocket(socket){
        this.sockets.push(socket);
        console.log('socket connected');
    }
}

module.exports = P2pServer;
```

when I try to run the following in the command line:

```
HTTP_PORT=3002 P2P_PORT=5003 PEERS=ws://localhost:5001 npm run dev
```

I get the following:

```
'HTTP_PORT' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

for some reason the process.env isn't picking up the input and passing it on to the app. What is wrong here?
Thanks!

EDIT: I was asked to add the `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "sf-chain",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --watchAll",
    "dev-test": "nodemon dev-test",
    "start": "node ./app",
    "dev": "nodemon ./app"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^23.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "ws": "^5.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: You're receiving the error because this is really not a command. You should use just `npm run dev`. Please, show your `package.json` file

Comment: @MatheusReis i added the package.json code. That being said - the command is the exact same command the instructor uses in the course..

Comment: I guest you use windows and it doesn't support to set ENV in command line that way

Comment: Oh! I didn't stop to think about that. wow. Need to figure this out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using:

```
$ HTTP_PORT=3002 P2P_PORT=5003 PEERS=ws://localhost:5001 npm run dev
```

It is showing an error, because the window powershell will not recognize this command..

Instead you should use:

```
set HTTP_PORT=3002 && set P2P_PORT=5002 && set PEERS=ws://localhost:5001 && npm run dev
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe were doing the same course. I'm sure you've probably figured this out but I tried the same step in Git Bash instead of Powershell and it worked.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32190460)

Comment: The solution did in fact work...